# WPF treeview и checkboxes. Как отметить родительский узел?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть вот такой DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate">    
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
              Checked="onCheck" Unchecked="OnUnckecked" Tag="{Binding Path=fullName}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </CheckBox>    
</DataTemplate>
```

Заполняю treeview через него:

```
TreeViewItem _item = new TreeViewItem();
//////
Folder child = new Folder()
{
    Name = String.Format("{0} ({1}:)", drive.VolumeLabel, drive.Name[0]),
    IsSelected = false, fullName = drive.Name
};
TreeViewItem _node = new TreeViewItem();
_node.Header = child;
_node.HeaderTemplate = FindResource("FolderTemplate") as DataTemplate;
_node.Tag = drive.Name;
_node.Expanded += TreeViewItem_Expanded;
_item.Items.Add(_node);

FolderTree.Items.Add(_item);
```

События с checkbox-ами срабатывают, но мне еще нужно вызвать OnCheck на родительский узел. Подскажите, как это сделать, с xaml я пока на "вы".

Comment: Перечитал несколько раз и так и не понял что Вам нужно.. Когда Вам нужно вызвать OnCheck на родительский узел? Действительно ли Вам нужно его вызывать или достаточно изменить значение? Попробуйте более подробно описать проблему..

Comment: При OnCheck sender-ом является checkbox. Мне нужно получить treeViewItem соответствующий этому checkbox. А через него уже отметить родителя.

Comment: Расширьте, пожалуйста, немного листинг. Не совсем понятно что потом происходит с _node.

Comment: Расширила, но там ничего принципиального не происходит, просто добавление.

Comment: Если вы уж собираете ваш UI вручную, то вы можете вручную и навесить обработчик (`_node.Checked += DoWhateverYouWant(FolderTree)`). Но такого вам не должно хотеться, в WPF такого рода логике принадлежит view model'и (а UI конструируется через xaml).